# In Dart, how can a subclass extend a superclass, having a generic type of the subclass extend a type of the superclass?

Tags: generics, dart, flutter

This is a **Dart Generics** question. This question is simpler then it seems, please keep reading.

I have:

- class SomeController uses type T
- class ExtendedController uses type S
- ExtendedController extends SomeController
- S extends T.

**The below code doesn't work:**

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class SomeValue {}

class ExtendedValue extends SomeValue {}

abstract class SomeController<T extends SomeValue> extends ValueNotifier<T> {
  SomeController(T value) : super(value);

  factory SomeController.create() {
    return ExtendedController();
  }
}

class ExtendedController extends SomeController<ExtendedValue> {
  ExtendedController() : super(ExtendedValue());
}
```

I get the error :

*`The return type 'ExtendedController' isn't a 'SomeController<T>', as defined by the method 'create'.`*

in the `return ExtendedController();` line.

**I then changed it to this:**

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class SomeValue {}

class ExtendedValue extends SomeValue {}

abstract class SomeController<T extends SomeValue> extends ValueNotifier<T> {
  SomeController(T value) : super(value);

  factory SomeController.create() {
    return ExtendedController();
  }
}

class ExtendedController<S extends ExtendedValue> extends SomeController<S> {
  ExtendedController() : super(ExtendedValue());
}
```

Still doesn't work, but now I get another error: 
*`The constructor returns type 'ExtendedValue' that isn't of expected type 'S'.`*

this time in the `super(ExtendedValue());` line.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An explicit cast fixes it:

```
  factory SomeController.create() {
    return ExtendedController() as SomeController<T>;
  }
```

https://groups.google.com/a/dartlang.org/forum/#!topic/misc/bVRHdagR8Tw

alternatively you can use

```
  static create() {
    return ExtendedController() as SomeController<T>;
  }
```

With optional `new` there isn't a difference anymore.

Comment: Interesting that with optional new there isn't a difference anymore, indeed. Rigorously speaking, classes shouldn't know about their subclasses, and if this were Java I would create a separate SomeControllerFactory class to encapsulate the logic of returning one of SomeController's subclasses. I guess I feel better about breaking this best practice in Dart because of that word "factory" in there. Of course, what I just said is not all that important, but I feel that the first form is a bit clearer, semantically.

Comment: I strongly agree with **Rigorously speaking, classes shouldn't know about their subclasses**. So I would suggest to not to have `factory` methods for `abstract class`.

Comment: It depends on who controls the subclasses. If the class has only private constructors and therefore only the developer of the base class can create subclasses, I wouldn't make this a strong rule.

Answer (score 1):

Let's take the first error:
`The return type 'ExtendedController' isn't a 'SomeController<T>', as defined by the method 'create'.`

It is telling `ExtendedController` is **not an expected return type** from `create` method as per definition.

`create` is a **factory** method here it and expects the return type to be `SomeController`

```
factory SomeController.create() {
  return SomeController();
}
```

We cannot change like this also as `SomeController` is an **abstract** class.
So, I moved the `factory` method to ExtendedController.

```
class SomeValue {}

class ExtendedValue extends SomeValue {}

abstract class SomeController<T extends SomeValue> extends ValueNotifier<T> {
  SomeController(T value) : super(value);
}

class ExtendedController extends SomeController {
  ExtendedController(ExtendedValue value) : super(value);

  factory ExtendedController.create() {
    return ExtendedController(ExtendedValue());
  }
}
```

Hope my explanation helps up to some extent.

Comment: My example is a simplification. In the real code there are many extended controller classes, and the factory chooses one of them to return, depending on parameters passed to it.